# My css won't work within a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/images/files/js/callback.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

in the callback.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/images/files/css/style.css" ></script>');
document.write('<link src="/images/files/js/core.js">');
}
```

About some reason it will add al the text of the callback.js file into my page but won't load the style.css and the core.js, So when I visit the page the elements of callback.js will be in the head element but they don't work on the page, so I have a page without css and js

second thing I want to achieve is that if it has load all the content of the callback.js it will remove the link to callback.js so that file isn't visible anymore

The reason I want to do this is in javascript/jquery is because I hate php and I've a lot of pages with exactly the same links in it.

Comment: You need to have `link` block instead of `script` for CSS.

Comment: Stil not working, the javascript also won't load

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: you cannot use document.write on ready event, you need to dinamycally append into the header. And why are you using a script tag to load a css file?

Comment: Why are you doing this - `'<scr'+'ipt ` ?

Comment: To add to what @FabrizioCalderan said, you can't use `<link>` for a script file. Also, it's `href` instead of `src` when including css files.

Comment: That wont work  in any ways. As you dont have refernced jquery first.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   /* creating script and link elements */

   var style = $('<link />', {
       'href': '/images/files/css/style.css',
       'rel': 'stylesheet'
   });
   var core  = $('<script />', { 
       'src': '/images/files/js/core.js'
   });


   /* append style and core */

   var head  = $('head');
   style.appendTo(head);
   core.appendTo(head);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/images/files/css/style.css" ></script>');
```

to,

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/images/files/css/style.css" >');
```

Comment: -1 document.write() is a bad idea. See my comments on @Ani's answer.

Comment: @xec: Agreed. But I just wanted to correct the OP's mistake in the logic. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You write :

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/images/files/css/style.css" ></script>');
```

You are trying to include a CSS file in a script tag. Use instead :

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/images/files/css/style.css"/>');
```